# Creating and Storing a Record with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've set up the following model:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter});
App.store = App.Store.create();
App.Proposal = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('description')
});
App.Proposal.FIXTURES = [...];
```

That works great, and my app pulls out my fixture data and sets it all up. I can move around my app without issues.

Since displaying data works, I created a route to create a new Proposal. I can't figure out how to save it back to my data store though, and I think I'm doing everything correctly. Here's what I'm doing:

```
App.ProposalsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    newRecord: function() {
        this.set('content', App.Proposal.createRecord());
    },
    actions: {
        saveNewProposal: function() {
            var newProposal = App.Proposal.createRecord({...});
            newProposal.save();
            this.transitionToRoute('proposals.index');
        }
    }
});

App.ProposalsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.newRecord();
    }
}
```

When `newProposal.save()` is called, nothing appears in the datastore. My other concern is that most of the documentation says I should use `this.store` instead of `App.Proposal` when creating the record, but then that generates the following error:

```
TypeError: Object proposal has no method '_create'
```

What is the proper way to create and save a record? Or is it just because I'm using the FixtureAdapter?

Comment: Can you post the Ember Data version you are using?

Comment: I pulled it down with bower (which this is my first time messing with it, so I've probably messed something up), and it's v0.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed using a fairly old version of Ember Data.

Here's a quick example of Ember with a 1.0 beta version of ED.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/73/edit

Here's some basic concepts that you'll need to change:

### You don't need to create the store anymore, you create adapters

#### Application wide adapter

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter;
```

#### Model specific adapter

```
App.ColorAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;
```

### Model creation/finding

#### Creating a model (from a route/controller)

```
this.get('store').createRecord('color', {name: 'green'});
```

#### Finding a model (from a route/controller)

```
this.get('store').find('color'); //find all of the colors

this.get('store').find('color', 1); //find color id 1
```

You'll want to glance over the Ember Data transition, which will be published as soon as they actually go to ED 1.0.  That's why the documentation is so out of date.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md